# Why did Fury respond that way?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-marvel-2019, spider-man-far-from-home, nick-fury

After reading [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/216181/why-were-these-characters-absent-in-spider-man-far-from-home) question, I remember wondering about this while watching the movie:

In *Spider-Man: Far From Home*,

> When Spider-Man tries to get a pass from helping fight the Elementals, he brings up names of people who can help instead of him. Fury has an answer for each name, but when Spider-Man suggested Captain Marvel, Fury's response was really strict and he was not willing to even consider hearing about it.

However, in *Captain Marvel*

> I remember them being in good terms. Even somehow friendly.

When was that change of relations?

Comment: This is the MCU son! You gotta stay til the end of the credits!

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I did! with Mysterio's video screening to the world. Was there another??

Comment: Aye, there were two post credits scenes. You have to stay until the end's end.

Comment: @MorZamir: you seem to have misunderstood the phrase “end of the credits”. If you can still see the names of people who worked on the movie (those are credits) scrolling up the screen, then they haven't ended. MCU movies tend to put [a bunch of stuff](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87312/do-all-marvel-films-have-a-second-non-foreshadowing-post-credits-scene/145268#145268) there!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is no change in relation, this is one of those subtle hints to hint at the fact that, that was Talos and not Fury. This [article at Fandango](https://www.fandango.com/movie-news/marvels-kevin-feige-on-the-mcu-multiverse-far-from-home-post-credits-scenes-and-the-future-of-spider-man-753812) also gives a bit more information on the subtle hints throughout the film.

> **For sure when Fury is whispering to himself something about the Kree, I was like, “Wow, that’s weird.” And when he says, “Where’s Captain Marvel?” “Never invoke that name.” Looking back I get, but now I want to see others. Sam’s performance has to change, because he’s different obviously.**
>
> Jon Watts: Now that you know that secret, you can watch all of the Nick and Maria scenes again. There’s a lot of little things like that.
>
> <sub>[Screen Rant, Jon Watts Interview: Spider-Man: Far From Home](https://screenrant.com/spiderman-far-home-jon-watts-interview/)</sub>

Carol is sort of like a saviour to the Skrull and Talos respects and likes her for her actions. His reaction is either protecting her as she doesn't need to come here or he's not wanting her to come due to her power of sarcasm.

Comment: And frankly, with her level of power, Cpt Marvel is like the last resort “nuke option”. Only called upon if all others have failed. She’d be overkill to deal with Mysterio.

Comment: @MissouriSpartan Not really, if she was available ___and___ around you'd certainly not leave her having a drink in a bar somewhere until all your other heroes have had their asses handed to them but rather ask for her help straight away.

Comment: That’s the key.........if she was around. Remember she has thousands of other worlds to help. Of all we know she was across the galaxy at that moment. Remember too, the elementals didn’t end up being the major threat they appeared to be anyway.

Comment: @MissouriSpartan Your first comment read like you thought it didn't matter where she was, next door or the other side of the galaxy. I get your point now though and agree with it. You also don't want to waste time not trying to stop it whilst she travels over.

Comment: no. What I said was: IF she is around she’d be overkill for something like this. The elementals ended up being no big deal comparatively. Would you launch a nuke to end a large fist fight, if the person with the launcher wasn’t busy with bigger battles elsewhere? Or would you use your other lesser-powered assets first?

Comment: @MissouriSpartan Well that's not a comparable example because Carol can alter how powerful she is, she could only fist fight or she could go full Binary. She's intelligent and can adjust as needed. Also you can't really use the Elementals being fake in that argument because the scene in question happened before anyone knew they were.